# Apache Django settings.py error

Tags: python, django, apache

I am getting following error in error_logs of apache, can anyone help?

opt/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/defaults.py:3:    DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
     [Thu Jun 20 10:35:49 2013] [error]   DeprecationWarning)

and at browser level

```
ImportError at /
No module named list_detail
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://codereview.zk.com/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named list_detail
Exception Location: /opt/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ReviewBoard-1.7.5-   py2.7.egg/reviewboard/reviews/views.py in <module>, line 22
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

set in settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '172.1623.20.1333']

Answer (score 3):

In Django 1.5 there is no list_detail module anymore. There is django.views.generic.list module.

You shoud read migration document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/

Comment: I downgraded =1.3 & error now
    File "/opt/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call_

Comment: Could You provide full traceback?